# Creating class fields in the constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, upcasting

I recently started learning Java. I got to the point of upcasts and downcasts and this is what I encountered. I understand how type conversion works, but this moment keeps me awake. If you create class fields outside the constructor and assign values to them, then during the upcast, as per the rules, you cannot get the field of the child class, but if these fields are created directly in the constructor, then during the upcast I can safely refer to the fields of the child class.

`Parent` class:

```java
public class Parent {
    String name = "Parent name";
    int age = 30;

    Parent() {

    }

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("Parent say hello");
    }
}
```

`Child` class with creation in constructor:

```java
public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child() {
        this.name = "Child name";
        this.age = 10;
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("CHild say hello");
    }
}
```

`Child` class with creation out constructor:

```java
public class Child extends Parent {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Child() {
        this.name = "Child name";
        this.age = 10;
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("CHild say hello");
    }
}
```

`Main` code testing first case:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        System.out.println(p.name);
    }
}
```

Output: `Child name`

`Main` code testing second case:
(The `Main` code is the same.)
Output: `Parent name`

I looked at a ton of video tutorials and documentation sites, but no one considered my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first test case, class `Parent` is instantiated and the string *Parent name* is assigned to member variable `name` in class `Parent`. Then the `Child` class is instantiated and its constructor assigns a new value to member `name` in class `Parent`, namely *Child name*. Now in method `main`, of class `Main`, `p.name` will return the current value of variable `name` in class `Parent` which is *Child name*.

In the second test case, you are creating another `name` variable in class `Child`. This is a different variable to `name` in class `Parent`. Hence when you assign a value to `name` in the constructor of class `Child`, you are assigning it to the variable in class `Child` and **not** to the variable in class `Parent`. Hence `name` in class `Parent` is still *Parent name*. So, in method `main`, of class `Main`, `p.name` refers to `name` in class `Parent` (even though you assign `p` to an instance of class `Child`) and therefore the second test case prints *Parent name*.

```java
Parent p = new Child();
```

Here `p` is a `Parent` and not a `Child` and therefore has no access to member variables in class `Child`. This is known as [variable hiding](https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java). There are many questions (and answers) regarding variable hiding. Just enter the following in the search box at the top of this Web page:

```
[java] variable hiding
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted to see!!!